# sbt docker:Publish - app crashes but container doesn't

Tags: scala, docker, sbt-native-packager

I'm building docker images for my Scala applications using the sbt-native-packager plugin. I noticed that when the process inside a container crashes (log shows `Exception in thread "main"...` and the process is definitely dead), the container is still "alive":

```
me@my-laptop$ docker exec 5cca ps
PID TTY          TIME CMD
  1 ?        00:00:08 java
152 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

The generated Dockerfile is:

```
FROM java:openjdk-8-jre
WORKDIR /opt/docker
ADD opt /opt
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon:daemon", "."]
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/the-app-name"]
CMD []
```

where `bin/the-app-name` is a pretty big auto-generated bash script that gathers all the necessary parameters (classpath, main class name, etc.) and runs the app using the `java` command. So my guess is that something about this setup makes docker consider the container to be "running" as long as the JVM is running, regardless of my code crashing...

Any idea how i can cause my container to exit when the app crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting it looks like there's a thread-leak somewhere that prevents the application from exiting. I'm suspecting it may be coming from the akka ActorSystem but did not find it yet.
Either way, catching the exception on the main thread and calling `System.exit(1)` causes the java process to die and the container stops.

Answer (score 0):

When running naked pods this behavior is expected, because naked pods are not rescheduled in the event of node failure.

When you deploy the pod, do you set the restartPolicy to "Always", "OnFailure" or "Never"?

The current status of the pod might be "Ok" right now, but this does not necessarily mean that the pod was not restarted before.
Can you run kubectl get po and print the output to check if the pod was restarted or not?

Info on naked pods here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#naked-pods-vs-replication-controllers-and-jobs

More info on restart policy: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle

Comment: Thanks Paula, but I'm not sure this is the root of the problem. Shouldn't I at least see the container as "stopped" or "crashed" or something, instead of "running"? Maybe this is not even a K8s problem, maybe I should build my container in another way so that it crashes when the Scala code inside it crashes.